# .shtml - how to redirect AND pass the URI

Tags: ssi, shtml

on my shared server, I'm trying to create a custom 404 page.  This particular host uses SHTML, and I cannot ReWrite..

I can display the uri:

```
<!--#echo var="REQUEST_URI" -->
```

I can make the URI a part of a variable:

```
<!--#set var="URI" value="404.php?xxx=$REQUEST_URI" -->
```

I can redirect to my own 404.php page:

```
<!--#exec cgi="404.php" -->
```

but I can't seem to put the URI variable's value into the redirect.  None of these work:

```
<!--#exec cgi="404.php?xxx=$REQUEST_URI" -->

<!--#exec cgi="$URI" -->

<!--#exec cgi="URI" -->
```

any ideas that will work?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on the `exec` element](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#element.exec):

> The CGI script is given the PATH_INFO and query string (QUERY_STRING)
>   of the original request from the client; these cannot be specified in
>   the URL path. The include variables will be available to the script in
>   addition to the standard CGI environment.

...

> The include virtual element should be used in preference to exec cgi.
>   In particular, if you need to pass additional arguments to a CGI
>   program, using the query string, this cannot be done with exec cgi,
>   but can be done with include virtual, as shown here:
>
> ```
> <!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/example.cgi?argument=value" -->
> ```

There are two options that could be taken:

- Use the `404.php` script via the existing `<!--#exec cgi` element. It should be able to use the relevant CGI variables immediately (e.g. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).
- Change to use an `<!--#include virtual` element and pass in the required variables.

Personally, I'd go with the first option.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't see a notice that told me this got answered. I appreciate it.